# scrollbar in html table

Tags: html

How to add scrollbar in each column of html table ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `overflow:scroll` for each column.

Comment: But you can't use it on a TD. Even using "display: block" will not add scrollbars to a TD.

Comment: @Kau-Boy:I mean, inside TD there we have to create a DIV of same height and width of TD. To that DIV we have to apply this overflow.

Comment: But than you have to say than (as I did earlier). Please don't answer with only a bit of the information :)

Comment: @Kau-Boy:Thanks for your suggestion. I will try to elaborate from the next time.

Answer (score 0):

You can't add a scrollbar to a cloumn, as far as I know. But you can do the following:

- Insert a DIV inside your table cell
- Set the height of that DIV to a fixed height
- Use "overflow: scroll;" on that DIV

If the content exceeds the height of the DIV you will see a scrollbar.

**EDIT**: If you want only a horizontal scrollbar you can use "overflow-x" if you only want a vertical scrollbar use "overflow-y".